# AirPlay Receiver documentation

Tags: ios, airplay, code-documentation

I am trying to find resources about Airplay for Windows, to be exact Windows Host acting as a *receiver*.

There are multiple applications out there. Just to name some: [reflector 3](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/features/mac-and-windows/), [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/PC).

I am wondering which language this is and on what reference this was build.

During my google research I couldn't find any reference.

Comment: I doubt you will find any documentation. Airplay is a proprietary protocol from Apple. The companies you mentioned have reverse engineered it and they are unlikely to share their efforts for other people to use.

Comment: Ah so that's the way, thanks then. I thought it might be public. 
Is this even legal?

Comment: It isn't public.  Apple also licenses the information to companies; e.g. Pioneer, Yamaha, Denon etc all include Airplay support in some of their products.  Is it legal? Ask a lawyer, not some random dude on the Internet :)